# Are ThreadPool settings global or only for work items?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, threadpool

If I set `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` in a WinForms application does this setting applies to only work items or for the whole assembly threads like timers and gui updates?

I'm building an application which will continuously process semi-short operations, usually around 1 minute each. I first came up with a manual thread creating version which works fine. Since I'm creating a new thread for each operation I'm looking if I can create a faster and more efficient version and I experimented with ThreadPool which didn't work better it even blocked my timer and gui updates. Is this normal or am I using it wrong?

Here's my pseude-code:

Manual Thread version: (all `MaxThread` and `ThreadCount` read and writes are done with locks)

```
timer1.Tick += Tick();

private void Tick()
{
    //do some text logging
    //do some TextBox updating
}

int MaxThreads = 10

while(true)
{
    if(ThreadCount < MaxThreads)
    {
        new Thread(() => Process()).Start();
        ThreadCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}

private void Process()
{
    //do something

    ThreadCount--;
}
```

ThreadPool version: (the computer is dual-core Xeon on 32bit Windows server OS)

```
timer1.Tick += Tick();

private void Tick()
{
    //do some text logging
    //do some TextBox updating
}

ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10,10) **<--removing this didn't help with freezing at all**

while(true)
{
    if(ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads() > 0)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(Process, null)
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}

private void Process()
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep(10000)` line confuses me. In what context is it invoked? *edit* The reason I'm asking is because it seems as if you're making the GUI thread sleep.

Comment: Zanathel: The method that has Thread.Sleep line is running in its own thread, not on the gui thread.

Answer (score 3):

According to my research on MSDN, limiting the number of `ThreadPool` threads will affect the following threading mechanisms:

- ThreadPool
- System.Threading.Timer
- System.Timers.Timer
- TPL Tasks

since under the hood they are using the thread pool to run their work.  
The following will run on their own thread:

- Thread
- BackgroundWorker

The GUI timers will run on the UI thread: `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that either method you are using here is not the best way to achieve what you want.

It is never wise to to second guess what the optimal number of threads a threadpool should have, and there are many factors that will have a bearing on this. Something the framework and OS are far more capable of doing.

In this case, you'd probably be better off making use a Sempaphore.

In answer to your question, there is a nice article about this here.

[Threadpool throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx)