# Does the ThreadPool reset the maximum threads after the code that sets it finishes? Should I manually do this?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-3.0, threadpool

I have written some (c# 3.5) batch processing code that can optionally override the thread pool maxthreads. It uses some pretty heavy resources that are not thread-safe, requiring a "resource pool" to be maintained with an item for each active thread. The consuming application can set a limit on how many threads the batch processor will use, which in turn calls `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()`. I'm doing this to test if manually setting a limit averages better performance than leaving it at the default setting.

My question is, should I reset the maxthreads back to the previous value for the application after each use of the batch processing code? It will be called intermittently throughout the day, possibly thousands of times. Will the MaxThreads limit persist forever until the application is restarted / it is set to a different value, or will it automatically reset?

While this isn't really a concern in my test harness, I'm wondering if I should update the code to "reset" the threadpool when the other resources are disposed after a batch completes for use in a production environment. Are there any implications to just leaving it overridden?

Finally, does setting the threadpool in one .net application set it for ALL applications on the box, or only for the context of that single app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't use `SetMaxThreads`.

This setting is per-process: Other processes are not affected, but your entire application is! This is called "**a global solution for a local problem**" and is considered a bad thing.

You want only some part of your app to be affected by this setting but you are affecting the whole app.

For example if you set max-threads to a low value to limit concurrency you will starve out the rest of the entire application including ASP.NET request threads and such.

For that reason I always prefer to solve such issues locally. Many TPL primitives (PLINQ, Parallel.*) allow you to set a max degree of parallelism. For simple tasks you can use a custom task scheduler which has a fixed number of threads (code available in the ParallelExtras).

Answer (score 1):

If you lower the level, the thread-pool will kill off threads which will (GoodThing™) reduce memory use (the stacks for all those threads), and (BadThing™) mean they have to be created again when you up the level again. It could also make the pool overly generous if there are lots of thread-pool-using tasks in the meantime (BadThing™) though it could well be that enough of them are blocking that the overall use of the pool is actually better (GoodThing™). Chances are though, that the use it is put to in that period is too low for it to make a differences (eh, IrrelevantThing™).

In all, I'd probably just set the pool to be as high as I ever will need it for the busy periods when the application starts, and then leave it alone. Dropping the level during other periods is worth experimenting with if there are performance issues during the rest of the application's run, but unless the memory or thread-use is a concern during these periods I wouldn't, since those threads are going to be used again in the future after all. Just setting the level once is simpler, and simpler is always better except when you can explain why it isn't ("as simple as possible, but no simpler").

Edit:

I wrote the above as a straight answer to the question, but the other answers that suggest not touching max-threads at all are really on the money. If you **really, really** need a very large number of threads, create them yourself (and either don't pool, or handle pooling yourself, depending on the importance of spin-up time). But before that, look at alternatives as it's not the best approach much of the time either.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly as msdn says:

"Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries you use.

Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching overhead becomes a significant factor."

And with a hosted solution the threads can be controlled (perhaps limited or even prevent from being altered) by IIS, depending on which version of IIS this could apply to all apps on the box, or to individual apps if their inherited settings are altered.

P.S. See this similar post for some more info and look at the threadpool throttling link for an interesting read [click me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466533/are-threadpool-settings-global-or-only-for-work-items)